# Summer Break - It's a *wrap*

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> I spent my summer in my backyard, enjoying some *candy* and an *icy beverage*.
>
> I was reading the newspaper, and my eyes *crossed* at the sight of the morning puzzle.
>
> It was a standard riddle, a *large play on words*, I thought. Bored, I put it away.
>
> I took a moment to enjoy the fresh *air*, and out of the *trimmed bushes* came my pal
>
> Asking to play humans vs *zombies*. I obliged, picking up my *small soaker*, and proceeded
>
> to chase him around my yard. But before I knew it, summer was gone.

What was I really thinking about all summer? How does it relate to the title?

P.S. I wasn't sure how hard or easy to make this (as it's my first puzzle), so I decided to err on the side of being too difficult. Let me know what you think!

Hint 1:

> The clues fit the word very very closely. In particular, each clue relates very closely to an example of the word. One of the words is exactly one of the examples :)

Hint 2:

> There is one pair of clues that are meant to go together: trimmed bushes and zombies. The rest are meant to be evaluated separately. The order of the clues also has no significance.

Hint 3:

> One of the words in the title may be a homophone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were actually thinking about

> the names of famous hip hop (rap) artists and groups

Explanation:

> *candy* = Eminem
>  *icy beverage* = Ice-T or Ice Cube
>  *crossed* = [Kris Kross](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kris_Kross)
>  *large play on words* = [Big Pun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Pun)
>  *air* = [Atmosphere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_(music_group))
>  *trimmed bushes, zombies* = [Flatbush Zombies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatbush_Zombies)
>  *small soaker* = Lil Pump

And, of course, the title

> “wrap” sounds like “rap”

Comment: PilsNot3 What you have so far is correct!

Comment: Rot13: Ovt Cha vf pbeerpg, nf vf yvy chzc. Nve naq ohfurf/mbzovrf vf gbhtu, ohg vs lbh gel tbbtyvat enc mbzovrf, lbh zvtug trg fbzrjurer.

Comment: Also, it's bushes, not hedges. It makes a difference.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for catching that! My first thought when I saw “trimmed bushes” was “hedges”

Answer (score 1):

> You were thinking of mobile games. Each of those italicized words has to do with some famous mobile game. 
>  
>  *Candy Crush Soda Saga* is candy + cold beverage
>  *4 Pics 1 Word* is crossed (literally) and a large play on words
>  *Plants vs. Zombies* could be "bushes (vs.) zombies"
>  
> I'll admit, "air" and "small soaker" might be a stretch for anything meaningful. And I don't have something for the title either.

Comment: That was not what I was thinking of, but if you could elaborate on how each clue fits, that would be great! Don't forget the title :) (I'm curious to see how you incorporate trimmed bushes and a large play on words)

Comment: Not a bad attempt! But, the true answer fits every clue ;)